# How to Archive Specific File Types with BAT and RAR?

Tags: batch-file, archive, rar

To archive my files I use a bat file with the code:

```
@set exclude=-x*.bmp -x*.png -x*.jpg
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a %exclude% "%cd%\MyStuff.rar" ".\MyFolder"
```

The problem is "MyFolder" is full of junk files and I just want a specific file type like *.txt. And I would like to turn the "exclude" into a "exclude everything except *.txt". How do I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved it myself. x for exclusion and n for inclusion. Works **EXACTLY** like I wanted it:

```
@set exclude=-x*.bmp -x*.png -x*.jpg
@set include=-n*.txt -n*.pdf
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a %include% "%cd%\MyStuff.rar" ".\MyFolder"
```

Comment: Do not see you using the exclude in the final command though?

Comment: is this recursive (also looks in subfolders)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I use my script for a long time now.